# How to get previous date in java/joda-time excluding week ends

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am using this code to get previous date but i would like to get the date excluding `Saturday and Sunday`

the code that i use to get previous date :

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static String previousDateString(String dateString) 
            throws ParseException {
        // Create a date formatter using your format string
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        // Parse the given date string into a Date object.
        // Note: This can throw a ParseException.
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

        // Use the Calendar class to subtract one day
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

        // Use the date formatter to produce a formatted date string
        Date previousDate = calendar.getTime();
        String result = dateFormat.format(previousDate);

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateString = "2012-08-20";

        try {
            // This will print 2012-08-19
            System.out.println(previousDateString(dateString));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid date string");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`
```

It works fine but need to get the previous date which is not Saturday or Sunday.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have to *get* `DAY_OF_WEEK` from the `calendar` object and if its `next` day is `MONDAY` then subtract `three` days or if `SUNDAY` then subtract `two` days from the date/calendar object.

```
 calendar.setTime(myDate);
 int dayOfWeek=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
 if(dayOfWeek==Calendar.MONDAY)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3); 
 else
 if(dayOfWeek==Calendar.SUNDAY)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);
 else
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks it helped but why is this code : `if(dayOfWeek==Calendar.MONDAY)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);`

Comment: `int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY ) {
            calendar.setTime(myDate);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);
        } else if( day == Calendar.SUNDAY){
          calendar.setTime(myDate);
             calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);
        }` works fine and perfect.